# How to open a popup with Router Angular2?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am currently trying to make my angular2 app open a popup if I go to a specific URL.

Example : mywebsite.com/register

It should directly open a web page with the popup to register.

Currently I have :

MAIN.HTML

```
 <header></header>
<body-cmp></body-cmp>


<div class="row">
  <button md-raised-button class="md-raised md-primary" type="submit" ><a href="" [routerLink]="['/Login']">S'incrire</a></button>

</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<footer></footer>
```

MAIN.TS

```
@RouteConfig([
  {
    path: '/register',
    name: 'Login',
    component: LoginCmp
  }
])
```

It's working my
Login.html is loaded but how can I remove the header,body and footer and also make appear a popup ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe will be useful for some googling people :) https://vsavkin.com/angular-2-router-d9e30599f9ea#.5i699nkjd
In short: using router links like /login(popup:message/hello) we render popup components in appropriate outlets. App component contains:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="popup"></router-outlet>
```

Comment: Is this best practice to use pop ups in routes ? As in our project I've 100+ popup and there would be 5-10 different modules...Could you suggest me an architecture for that....